# Access a query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I have in my controller this:

```
@itemsok =  Search.where("first_item_id = ?", params["3"])
```

This is sopposed to be a query in the search table of the database asking for all the searches that have a first_item_id = 3 ...

Question 1 .- The syntax is I found it in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html but im not sure if im using it right?

Ok the question 2 is, I have this on the controller, is it ok to have querys in the controller?

In the view im printing the variable <%= @itemsok %> and all I get is a

```
ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fd3d3e894d8
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also new to rails, can you try this: @itemsok =  Search.where("first_item_id = ?",3)

Comment: Not working mate :( I've tried many syntax methods but no success... How would you print it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord 3 lets you chain relations together so you can do something like this:

```
@itemsok = Search.where("first_item_id = ?", params["3"]).where("foo = ?", "bar")
```

The `where()` function returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.  Generally this isn't a problem, since if you use the object it'll automatically run the query and return the results on the object so you'll get the database objects.  AR doesn't run the query until it's actually needed.

Where will return a list of items (Array), so if you're just debugging, change your view to this:

```
<%= debug @itemsok.to_a %>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much Andrew, do you know the method for handling the information, if I am not just debugging... Just a hint of this and I will look for it. Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by handling the information?  You just call methods on the @itemsok (remember it's an array) and it'll return the data in the database table.  For example: `@itemsok.map { |item| item.first_item }`

Comment: it's more idiomatic to pass a hash to where.

Comment: Agreed, but he's clearly a beginner and I didn't want to confuse him too much.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be constructing the query wrong way.

If you want to search for records with first_item_id = 3, you should do:

`Search.where("first_item_id = ?", 3)`

This will return an array of matching records, something you can't easily print with `<%= @itemsok %>`. You should iterate over the elements and print each one:

```
<% @itemsok.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

I'd also suggest defining `to_s` method for the objects you want to print.

```
class Search
  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Then you can simply print the object and `to_s` method will be automatically called for you:

```
<% @itemsok.each do |item| %>
  <%= item %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That should be `item` not `@item`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do is to define a `namedscope` in the model and then use it in the controller.

Something similar to this :

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
 named_scope:item_ok,lambda {|*args|{:conditions=>["item_id >= ?", args.first]}} 
end
```

and then call the `namedscope` from the controller like this :

```
@itemsok = Search.item_ok(params[:value])
```